# Print integers as strings in mips programs

Tags: assembly, mips, compiler-theory

This is my python code and I need to convert this to MIPS

```
Print (“Enter two numbers here:”)
a = int (input())
b = int (input())
sum=a+b

print(“sum is =” + str (sum))
```

I am having difficulty in trying to print int values (which I get as input) as strings. Please help.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Tagged question integer is printed as an integer. In my case, it has to be printed as a string.

Comment: Printing as integer involves converting it to a string.